# Querying columns that don't exist, doesn't fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Strange situation.

If I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, title VARCHAR(20), someIntCol INT)
GO
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT, t1Id INT, someData VARCHAR(20))
GO
```

and do:

```
SELECT    t1.* 
FROM    t1 
WHERE    t1.id IN (SELECT someIntCol FROM t2)
```

weird thing: the parser doesn't mind that the column someIntCol doesn't exist

weirdest thing: if I change someIntCol to someIntCol2, I get a "Invalid column name 'someIntCol2'." error

Can anyone explain that?

FYI, this is not my code. I got it from [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx) link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT    t1.* 
FROM    t1 
WHERE    t1.id IN (SELECT t2.someIntCol FROM t2)
```

This will now throw an exception when executed.

Because `someIntCol` exists in `t1`, it is using that data item from the main query.

Sub-queries are able to use data items from the main query. Therefore to avoid this, specify the table name when entering your data item:

```
SELECT [TableName].[ColumnName]
```

This will also prevent ambiguity if you have 2 columns with the same name in `t1` and `t2`

---

Heres an MSDN which may give you a better understanding of how subqueries work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213262(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: +1 : Always specify the table names, else you may be referencing columns from another table, possibly from a wider scope.

Comment: Not really. This query will also parse fine as it is parseable. Doesn't matter if stuff exists or not in the parse step.

Comment: @cairnz I've edited my answer to specify execution. I'm confident it will throw exception on execution, but not on parse.

Comment: I understand the explanation, but I don't understand how can you select a column (that is from t1) from t2.

Comment: @Diego - This is because `t2` is within a sub-query of `t1`, and sub-queries have access to the main query items

Comment: @Diego I've updated the answer with a link to an msdn article which may help you better understand subqueries

Comment: It confused me a lot too. From the [MS SQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16): _If a column is referenced in a subquery that does not exist in the table referenced by the subquery's FROM clause, but exists in a table referenced by the outer query's FROM clause, the query executes without error. SQL Server implicitly qualifies the column in the subquery with the table name in the outer query._

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server the parse step only semantically checks the syntax, for things like unescaped columns beginning with numbers, like `[2ndColumn]` and not `2ndColumn` (which will fail parsing) , keywords and such, and makes sure the query can be *parsed*. This is the process that happens when you click the parse button in SSMS. This process doesn't validate the query against the underlying data.

Therefore i can type in `SELECT abc FROM DEF` even though i don't have any column named abc, and not even a tabled named DEF.

The next step is the algebrizer, which is the process of binding. This step (which doesn't occur when you just parse the query), makes sure **that every object of your query**  actually exist, and will fail when you are referring to non-existing objects.

Another way to verify this is to tell SQL Server to only parse, and not do anything else:

```
SET PARSEONLY ON
SELECT abc FROM def
GO
```

Above query will say "Command(s) executed successfully."

```
SET PARSEONLY OFF
SELECT abc FROM def
GO
```

Above query will say "Invalid object name 'def'."

In your example question, the column someIntCol exists within the scope of your query, because you have not specified a specific origin from it. It doesn't make much sense, resultwise, but it's still not an invalid query.

Comment: I gave you a vote because it is a very good knowledge. I also may have misused the word "parse". My point is that the query ran even though the columns doesn't exist. But now I see that I does on table 1. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Parser don't mind becase "he see" column someIntCol in t1. You didn't specify from what table he should take someIntCol so parser "assumed" you want it from t1.

Answer (score 0):

Can u find that

```
SELECT    t1.*  FROM    t1  WHERE    t1.id IN (SELECT someIntCol FROM t2)
```

Table T2 didnt have the column "someIntCol".

so the parser shows the error